# Google Analytics Event tracking for downloads not working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

UA-*******-1I'm trying to track file downloads on my site using GA Event Tracking. Here's my GA code, just before `</head>`:

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Here's my script to do the download tracking:

```
$('a.track-dl').click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'testcategory', 'testaction', 'testlabel']);

})
```

I've checked in Chrome Google Analytics debugger, and see this (identifying info hidden):

```
Account ID               : UA-*******-1
Page Title               : ************
Host Name                : ************
Page                     : ************
Referring URL            : 0
Hit ID                   : 961963542
Hit Type                 : event
Event Name               : testcategory
Event Type               : testaction
Event Label              : testlabel
```

But the events never show up in GA. If it matters, I'm using a profile with a filter to only show traffic to a particular subdomain (this event is occuring on that subdomain). All my pageviews show up in about 10 mins of me performing them.

I'm seeing this on the Events overview page:

### 5 of your visits sent events

> **Total Events: 0
>
>   Unique Events: 0
>
>   Event Value: 0
>
>   Avg. Value: 0.00
>
>   Visits with Event: 0
>
>   Events / Visit: 0.00**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out my problem. The download was canceling the request for __utm.gif.

Used the method suggested here: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527 to add a `setTimeout()` to the download request.

Hacky, but I guess it's currently the only way to do it.